# Сортировка элементов массива

Tags: php, массивы

Имеется многомерный массив, выглядит он следующим образом:

```
$arr = 
[
    'test' => 
    [
        '11', '22'
    ],

    'myArray' => 
    [
        'key 1', 'key 2'
    ],

    'net' => 
    [
        'text 1', 'text 2'
    ]
];
```

Как мне отсортировать этот массив так, что бы в ответе получилось:

```
    11
    key 1
    text 1
    22
    key 2
    text 2
```

Т.е. сначала брать значение (`11`) с первого ключа первого под массива (`test`), затем переключиться на 2-й под массив (`myArray`) к первому ключу (`0`) и взять оттуда значение (`key 1`), и тоже самое сделать с 3-м под массивом, и по окончанию выполнить эти действия снова, но на этот раз нужно взять `22` из `test` и `key 2` из `myArray` и так, с `net`, до тех пор, пока все ключи не закончатся

Answer (score 2):

Во-первых, это не сортировка, а какой то обход в нужно порядке. В целом такие тройки получить вам поможет обычный `array_map`

```
$result = array_map(null, ...array_values($arr));
```

на выходе получите двумерный массив вида

```
11,    key 1,    text 1
22,    key 2,    text 2
```

дальше вы, например, можете обойти его с `array_walk_recursive()` и как раз получите искомый порядок.
Либо сделать его плоским, например так:

```
$result = call_user_func_array('array_merge', $result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно конечно использовать тысячу и одну стандартную функция пятьдесят два раза, а можно написать простенький цикл -

```
$new_arr = [];
for( $i = 0; $i <= 1; $i ++ ) {
    foreach($arr as $k => $v) {
       $new_arr[] = $arr[$k][$i];
    }
}
```